# Cannot click on cookie banner button using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am unable to click the cookie accept button on this site: https://www.verivox.de/privathaftpflicht/

This is the code I used:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.verivox.de/privathaftpflicht/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="uc-btn-accept-banner"]'))).click()
```

It simply does nothing, no error message. The banner just stays there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button to accept the cookies is contained in the object `div.cmp-container`, which has the property `display: table`, so you can get rid of the banner by simply setting it to `none`:

```
banner = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.cmp-container')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'none';", banner)
```